# Multiple bi-directional gRPC calls over single pre-established TCP connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, firewall, grpc

Is it possible to use [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/) such that all calls between two remote hosts
use a TCP connection that is established outside of gRPC? I would also like
to determine whether this TCP connection can be multiplexed for more than
one gRPC call, that the calls may be in either directions, and that gRPC
not close the socket.

The intent is to be able to use gRPC when two ends of gRPC are across a
firewall. The firewall only allows establishing a single TCP connection
that is initiated from within the firewall.

For the requirements only C++ and Java implementations may be on either side.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. The main problem will probably be that you don't want gRPC to close the socket; it's unclear when you want gRPC to release the socket back to you. It's also unclear whether you need this on server-side or client-side.

gRPC uses HTTP/2 which can naturally multiplex multiple bi-directional calls over a single TCP connection. C++ also allows you to [provide it an existing fd](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/3250). Java doesn't support passing an fd out-of-the-box, but it should be possible using the JNI Netty EpollSocketChannel. I would only expect those to work on client-side today, though.

This may be something that deserves [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/new) as a feature request.

Comment: The most desirable case would be where gRPC releases the socket to the user when it's API call is invoked. And, it would be desirable to have this capability on each of the server and client side. On the Java side it does not have to be a socket, but whatever equivalent abstraction that represents the fd. I will create a Github issue for feature request.

Comment: Opened Github request, and have [a response](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8217#issuecomment-249956071) that provides insight in the matter.